# Lumping "Else" cases together for counting

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I'm trying to do a count of items that match certain criteria, grouped by the value of a separate criterion. I want to display the count of each for values 0 through 4, then the count of everything greater than 4.

I'm trying:

```
SELECT
Count(*) as "Count", CASE
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) = 0 THEN "0" 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) = 1 THEN "1" 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) = 2 THEN "2" 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) = 3 THEN "3" 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) = 4 THEN "4"
ELSE ">4"
END
as "Days Ahead", CASE
WHEN slot.cancel_reason_id is NULL THEN "Kept"
ELSE "not kept"
END
as Status
FROM scheduling_manualapproval
JOIN scheduling_possiblereschedule ON
scheduling_manualapproval.related_suggestion_id = scheduling_possiblereschedule.id
JOIN scheduling_appointment AS slot ON 
          scheduling_possiblereschedule.available_slot_id = slot.id
WHERE scheduling_manualapproval.debug_info = ""
AND scheduling_manualapproval.action_type = 2
AND scheduling_manualapproval.action_complete = 1
group by TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time), status
```

I was hoping this would give me:

```
Count - Days Ahead - Status
55    - 0          - Kept
52    - 0          - Not-Kept
140   - 1          - Kept
32    - 1          - Not-Kept
27    - 2          - Kept
19    - 2          - Not-Kept
147   - 3          - Kept
67    - 3          - Not-Kept
8     - 4          - Kept
534   - 4          - Not-Kept
90    - >4         - Kept
50    - >4         - Not-Kept
```

But instead I got:

```
Count - Days Ahead - Status
55    - 0          - Kept
52    - 0          - Not-Kept
140   - 1          - Kept
32    - 1          - Not-Kept
27    - 2          - Kept
19    - 2          - Not-Kept
147   - 3          - Kept
67    - 3          - Not-Kept
8     - 4          - Kept
534   - 4          - Not-Kept
10    - >4         - Kept
5     - >4         - Not-Kept
20    - >4         - Kept
15    - >4         - Not-Kept
30    - >4         - Kept
25    - >4         - Not-Kept
25    - >4         - Kept
3     - >4         - Not-Kept
5     - >4         - Kept
2     - >4         - Not-Kept
```

Where all of the >4 cases where separated instead of being lumped together. How do I get them to be lumped?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use column aliases for aggregation.  So:

group by "Days Ahead", status

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT
  Count(*) as "Count", 
  CASE
    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) > 4 THEN '>4' 
    ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) 
  END as "Days Ahead", 
  CASE
    WHEN slot.cancel_reason_id is NULL THEN 'Kept'
    ELSE 'not kept'
  END as Status
FROM 
  scheduling_manualapproval
  JOIN scheduling_possiblereschedule ON scheduling_manualapproval.related_suggestion_id = scheduling_possiblereschedule.id
  JOIN scheduling_appointment AS slot ON scheduling_possiblereschedule.available_slot_id = slot.id
WHERE 
  scheduling_manualapproval.debug_info = ''
  AND scheduling_manualapproval.action_type = 2
  AND scheduling_manualapproval.action_complete = 1
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) > 4 THEN '>4' 
    ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, scheduling_manualapproval.approved_on, slot.scheduled_date_time) 
  END, status
```

Don't use " for strings in SQL - use '. Though MySQL supports use of strings delimited by " most other vendors don't - getting into the habit of using ' keeps your database skills cross applicable

I modified your CASE WHEN to simplify it; there's no point essentially saying "if x = 1 then 1 elseif x = 2  then 2 elseif x = 3 then 3 elseif x = 4 then 4 else >4" - we can turn it round as "if X > 4 then '>4' else x" - i.e. just use X as the output value unless it's greater than 4

You ned to group by the result of the entire case when, not the result of the timestampdiff. What was going wrong before was that you were grouping by the value of the timestamp diff, so if it was 5, you were getting a group for 5. If 6, another group for 6. If 7, yet another group.. and so on. If you want "everything that is greater than 4" to just be a single group, then you have to transform the values 5, 6, 7, .. 999999 etc into a single value of '>4' using your case statement and group by the output of the case, not the output of the timestampdiff.

If it's hard to understand, let's look at a simpler example:

```
ID       Age
A        20
B        40
B        60
C        60

SELECT ID, AVG(Age) FROM t GROUP BY ID
A    20
B    50
C    60

SELECT CASE WHEN ID = 'A' THEN 'ayy' ELSE 'zed' END, AVG(Age) FROM t GROUP BY ID
ayy  20
zed  50
zed  60
```

The top query is fairly obvious, standard grouping. The bottom one is slightly more obscure; the grouping is still done on ID, but then after the grouping is done, ID is transformed: if it's 'A' it becomes 'ayy' else it becomes 'zed'. The grouping is allowed, it generated 3 groups because there are 3 distinct values of ID. It's OK to then transform the letters after the averages have been calced. 'zed' appears twice in the output because it's the B group relabeled and its also the C group relabeled. Of course, if we grouped by the CASE WHEN, then the transform would be done, THEN the group would be done:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ID = 'A' THEN 'ayy' ELSE 'zed' END, AVG(Age) FROM t 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ID = 'A' THEN 'ayy' ELSE 'zed' END
ayy  20
zed  53.33 --this is the (40 + 60 + 60)/3 (the B plus the other B plus the C, because they all transformed to zed before they were grouped)
```

Gordon's pointed out that you can group by the status alias, but i'd advocate NOT doing this, again for reasons of cross skilling - most other database vendors I've come across don't allow you to group by the aliased name in the select, they insist you group by the value that is selected before it is aliased.